# Why does this user have posts that appear to be older than their account?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, profile-page

Please refer to this profile: [Nathan Srivi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2585850/nathan-srivi)

The "member for" field on this profile page says "10 days", but he/she has posted several questions and answers that are more than 10 days old.

How did this happen?

Comment: Probably just an account merge?

Comment: As Mysticial says, he probably had two accounts merged for some reason.

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for Your response, I'm waiting for his/her response. Because I don't know that original reason. Surely I hope he/she know the real answer.  After that i will give the response

Comment: if you see in its reputation change of "-75" near "11,june" user was removed once. in SO I made mistake for `june/july`. now i wrote correct date

Comment: @jubinPatel How do you see that user removed activity? I can't find there

Comment: Unfortunately my account has been closed for some moderator. So i re open my account for the instructions of Stackoverflow team. Hey @DRAJI...thank you for view my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The profile history of that user says that he has 1 or more sock-pupets. Users action was detected by the moderator and all the sock-pupets has been removed. You can see this in his profile history for dated June 11 & June 26 section.

As per the rule one of his account remain active which is created by 10 days ago, that's why now his profile shows that account has been created 10 days ago but he has older posts within his merged profile.

You can also see the serial voteups on April 4, there may be many more which are now removed so we can't see them.

Answer (score 11):

Hmmm, the comments are close, but no cigar. ;P

His account had been destroyed for whatever reason, and it was recreated, or better yet "undestroyed," on July 16. The process of re-assigning their posts is manual on the part of the devs, but aside from just making up a registration date or using their earliest post date, I doubt there's any way of determining the *actual* date they registered their previous account. Probably not something anyone is concerned about. So yeah, the dates are off...

Comment: Reincarnation? *Awesome*!

Comment: Are you one of the moderator @animuson?

Comment: Great @animuson

Answer (score 10):

I received this email from the Stack Overflow team:

> Hi Nathan,
>
> I'm very sorry about the delay in getting back to you. It looks like
>   your accounts were mistakenly identified as belonging to another user
>   who was trying to circumvent some of the restrictions placed on his
>   account.
>
> I sincerely apologize for the inconvenience and confusion this has
>   caused. If you create a new account one more time and send me the link
>   to it, I will be happy to associate the posts you made under your
>   previous accounts with it and make a note on it to explain the
>   situation to the moderators who may be coming across your profile in
>   the future.

Thank you for reviewing my profile.

Comment: Ya fine, i have compared your answer with remaining 2 other's answers.I think both of them answers are more or less correct. You are perfectly correct. But this is not big thing.So i can't accept your answer.If i got an answer,i must accept the corrcet answer.It's my duty.But i have confused

Comment: @DRAJI Whats your problem. I am creating my account for past 6 month before. but Unfortunately my account has been closed for some moderator. So i am asking to support team. Stackoverflow team can retrieve my account and also include my old questions and answers.

Comment: No, Nothing!1st i wanted to know "how above problem was happened?".Now i have cleared.But Now i have one more doubt.How another user can closed your account? is this like hacking?

Comment: No @DRAJI. Its not a hacking. its moderator duty. moderator is also one of the member like you and me. you can earn more reputations. you get a rights to delete user and other. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: yeah, I saw that page. under the 'Access To Moderator Tools' privileges, it have an option delete post only, not user! if i made angry you, please forgive me!

Comment: @DRAJI, i got a reply from stackoverflow. moderators who may be coming across your profile in the future. So i understand moderators only delete my account. i dont know the clear reason for my account deletion.

Comment: Yes. I got. Refer this site url -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators.

Comment: Great Research @DRAJI

Comment: Thank you Mr/Miss@Nathan Srivi

Comment: @DRAJI Mr.Nathan

Comment: Ok. Thank you Mr.Nathan.

Comment: Now i have cleared and also accept an answer

Comment: Ok No problem. Mr/Miss.@DRAJI